# playing sounds won't work for me

Tags: java, audio

I tried making a simple file that would play a simple "gong.wav" file. I am using eclipse. I placed a copy of the gong.wav file in both the bin folder and the src folder. Then I ran this code (it, of course, contained the necessary imports).

```
public class Sound {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File gong = new File("gong.wav");
        System.out.println(gong.exists());
        playSound(gong);
    }
    static void playSound(File sound) {
        try {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound));
            clip.start();
            Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran this code, it didn't play the sound, Thread.sleep didn't do anything, and gong.exists() returned false. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you specify the absolute path, does that work?

Comment: You should also see an exception in the eclipse console, right?

Comment: @freedev One of my comments on your answer contains the error that I get in the eclipse console.

Comment: I have tried your code in my eclipse and it is working pretty well. I had just downloaded a [gong.wav file from internet](http://soundbible.com/2148-Chinese-Gong.html). I'll try to take a look at your comment, no promise, but my answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the file `gong.wav` into the project home.

Just to be clear, the project home is the directory where are `src` and `bin`.

```
project_home/bin
project_home/gong.wav
project_home/src
project_home/src/Sound.java
```

Comment: Well, this made gong.exists() return true, but I get an error. Here is the full error message that it outputs to the console:

Comment: javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
 at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.implOpen(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(Unknown Source)
 at Sound.playSound(Sound.java:16)
 at Sound.main(Sound.java:11)

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I looked at the discussion that you linked me to, and it looks like the guy in that discussion just ended up using a different java resource for playing sound. I want to get this working though.

Comment: I tried using a file called "01 Keo Lake.wav" and that didn't work.